# A Tensorflow training agnostic to Eager and Graph modes

Tags: tensorflow

I spend some of my time coding novel (I wish) RNN cells in Tensorflow. 
To prototype, I use eager mode (easier to debug). 
In order to train, I migrate the code to a graph (runs faster).

I am looking for a wrapper code/example that can run forward pass and training in a way that will be agnostic to the mode I run it - eager or graph, as much as possible. I have in mind a set of functions/classes, to which the particular neural network/optimizer/data can be inserted, and that these set of functions/classes could run in both modes with minimal changes between the two. In addition, it is of course good that it would be compatible with many types of NN/optimizers/data instances.

I am quite sure that many had this idea.
I wonder if something like this is feasible given the current eager/graph integration in TF.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I have been wondering the same. In the [Tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager#work_with_graphs) you can see:

> The same code written for eager execution will also build a graph during graph execution. Do this by simply running the same code in a new Python session where eager execution is not enabled.

But this is hard to achieve, mostly because working with graphs means dealing with placeholders, which can not be used in Eager mode. I tried to get rid off placeholders using object-oriented layers and the Dataset API. This is the closest  I could get to totally compatible code:

```py
m = 128  # num_examples
n = 5    # num features

epochs = 2
batch_size = 32
steps_per_epoch = m // 32

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    (tf.random_uniform([m, n], dtype=tf.float32),
     tf.random_uniform([m, 1], dtype=tf.float32)))
dataset = dataset.repeat(epochs)
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_dim=n),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

def train_eagerly(model, dataset):

    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

    print('Training graph...')
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        print('Epoch', epoch)
        progbar = tf.keras.utils.Progbar(target=steps_per_epoch, stateful_metrics='loss')
        for step in range(steps_per_epoch):
            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                features, labels = iterator.get_next()
                predictions = model(features, training=True)
                loss_value = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels, predictions)
            grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.variables)
            optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.variables))
            progbar.add(1, values=[('loss', loss_value.numpy())])

def train_graph(model, dataset):

    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
    iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()

    print('Training graph...')
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(iterator.initializer)
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        for epoch in range(epochs):
            print('Epoch', epoch)
            progbar = tf.keras.utils.Progbar(target=steps_per_epoch, stateful_metrics='loss')
            for step in range(steps_per_epoch):
                with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                    features, labels = sess.run(iterator.get_next())
                    predictions = model(features, training=True)
                    loss_value = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels, predictions)
                grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.variables)
                optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.variables))
                progbar.add(1, values=[('loss', loss_value.eval())])
```

As you can see, the main difference is that I use a one_shot_iterator during Eager training (of course, during graph training, I have to run operations within a session).

I tried to do the same using `optimizer.minimize` instead of applying the gradients myself, but I could not come up with a code that worked both for eager and graph modes.

Also, I'm sure this becomes much harder to do with not so simple models, like the one you are working with.